# var.sh is not exporting the variable using terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I want to export many paths using a .sh script. after running it nothing is exported I don't know why. so if anyone can advise.
This is the script used:

```
#!/bin/bash

txtrst=$(tput sgr0) # Text reset
txtred=$(tput setaf 1) # Red
echo "${txtred}## vars ##${txtrst}" 

T_D_L=/home/
T_D=$T_D_L
```

after that I use `echo $T_D_L` but nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using `./script.sh` to run, and the correct way is `source script.sh`